# The vagaries of information technology (aka what is meant by META?)

Tags: discussion, meta

I was instantly intrigued by what this site has to offer in the way of the revelation of information uncovered by its members or users. I am, however, convinced that my *very limited* knowledge of the inner sanctum in information technology may well force me to recognize the unpleasant understanding that I may indeed be in over my head. At the risk of annoying the other users, I am asking for their patience and kindness for those of us who learned the workings our PC's by working with them for the most part and may therefore not be cognizant of some of the most basic IT terminology.

So, what is meant by META? As I stumble around the site I promise to leave it alone if I am unable to get the hang of it. I've always been quick to grasp concepts but this is worlds away from my professional area of expertise.

Comment: I don't know what your area of expertise is.  Look up the defintions of three words: metaphyscs, metadata, and metanoia.  This will give you a handle on the prefix Meta.  Fron there you might guess that a meta site is a site for questions about the site.  To find out what meta is for, follow the link that has been provided.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that many [Stack Exchange sites](http://stackexchange.com/sites) have little to do with IT/Technology

Comment: This certainly is a garden path of a question.

Comment: It's true that many sites have little to do with IT/Technology.  However, each site has a Meta site associated with it.  The fact that the name "Meta" is used with all of them suggests that they are all parallel in function, as indeed they are.  To someone who doesn't get the parallel function from the word "Meta", this can all be a little mystifying.

Comment: Related: *[Meta Is Murder](https://blog.codinghorror.com/meta-is-murder/)* (posted just prior to the launch of the first meta site here)

Comment: "*I never metamorphosis I didn't like.*"